# What should i put in the username and password field in paypal check android sdk?

Tags: android, maven, gradle, paypal, sdk

I am using Paypal checkout android SDK(latest), but I am encountering some issues.

please refer to this:
https://developer.paypal.com/docs/business/native-checkout/android/
Go to step no 2.
In there, under maven, there are credentials(// Be sure to add these non-sensitive credentials in order to retrieve dependencies from the private repository.)
///////////
I don't know what should I put in the "non-sensitive credentials". Should I have to put the Paypal username(email id) and password or something else?

Any help will really be appreciated.
Please help friends.

Answer (score -1):

As the comment says, "be sure to add *these* non-sensitive credentials in order to retrieve dependencies from the private repository"

Use those credentials.

Comment: Which credintals bro?  Please tell me. That where I am stuck at.

Comment: The ones there.

Comment: where? please.!!!!! the paypal email id and password OR what

Comment: can you tell me where can i find "those credintals" you are telling. why are referring? can you please tell me straight

Comment: In the documentation you already linked and are referencing, https://developer.paypal.com/docs/business/native-checkout/android/#2-add-the-sdk-to-your-app

Comment: bro, please tell me straight. which credintals. plzzzzzzzzz. i beg you

Comment: dont refrence it.